# Conexión entre Android studio y PostgreSQL

Tags: android, postgresql

Buen día, necesito realizar una aplicación la cual su base de datos este alojada en `PostgreSQL` y no en `MySQL` pero la información sobre como hacerlo es muy difícil encontrarla veo que se puede hacer por **JDBC** pero algunos dicen que no es compatible o no es recomendado hay quienes dicen que se puede hacer consumiendo un servicio **API/REST** para conectarlo con `PostgreSQL` sin embargo no encuentro ninguna información al respecto, hay alguna documentación sobre el tema o porque es casi nula? es recomendado o que otras alternativas hay sobre esto?

Estuve tratando de hacer un **Login** y opte por usar un `JDBC`

```
public class clsConexionPG {

Connection conexion=null;

//Creamos nuestra funcion para Conectarnos a Postgresql
public  Connection conexionBD(){
    try{
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbcrud_postgresql", "postgres", "password");
        //conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://192.168.0.15:5432/madan_tumbes", "postgres", "admin");
    }catch (Exception er){
        System.err.println("Error Conexion"+ er.toString());
    }
    return  conexion;
}

//Creamos la funcion para Cerrar la Conexion
protected  void cerrar_conexion(Connection con)throws  Exception{
    con.close();
}
}
```

Pero recivo un error:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Tampoco encuentro nada relacionado a errores de conexión con `Android` y `PostgreSQL`

Realmente no se como proseguir a pesar de toda la investigación que he hecho, realmente agradecería que alguien me guié por cual camino debo ir o proveerme documentación o algún tipo de información sobre todo este tema, espero que alguien me pueda ayudar de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Hacerlo de manera directa es una muy mala idea, en todo lado encontrarás que lo ideal es ir por un API REST: `Aplicación móvil -> Conexión a un endpoint -> El endpoint -> conexión a Base de datos.`

Comment: No, rotuandamente no debes conectarte a la base de datos desde tu aplicacion, debes crear un servicio web para poder consumir los datos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que obtienes:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432
> refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the
> postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.

Se debe a que la conexión que tratas de realizar no puede ser posible, desde tu PC puedes acceder a localhost pero desde tu aplicación no es posible.

```
conexion = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbcrud_postgresql", "postgres", "Nicole_07");
```

Asegura publicar un dominio o ip mediante el cual se pueda acceder a tu base de datos, no debes usar `localhost`.

**Si estás utilizando el emulador de Android y tienes el PostgreSQL en tu misma PC no debes utilizar `127.0.0.1` o `localhost` como IP, debes utilizar `10.0.2.2`**

Revisa :

[Android - Espacio de direcciones de Red](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-networking)